Condition facetting of ggplot2 plot
I'm trying to create a univariate distribution plot with ggplot2 that optionally allows us to provide a faceting variable.
My goal is to conditionally create facets for a density plot. Below, I create a function that works with a single unquoted variable. The moment I add an unquoted facetting variable, that variable is unable to be found.
The last line of code below should provide a density plot for gear levels 3, 4, and 5.
library(ggplot2)

# univariate density function w/ conditional facetting
univar_plot <- function(df, var, facet_var = NULL) {
  
  # create density plot
  p <- df |> ggplot(aes(x = {{var}})) + geom_density()

  # Conditional faceting
  if(!is.null(facet_var)) p <- p + facet_wrap(vars( {{facet_var}} ))
  # plot
  p
}

univar_plot(mtcars, mpg) # works
univar_plot(mtcars, mpg, facet_var = gear) # Error: object 'gear' not found


You can get the facets by providing a quoted column name and using get to supply that as a variable to ggplot:
univar_plot <- function(df, var, facet_var = NULL) {
  
  # create density plot
  p <- df |> ggplot(aes(x = {{var}})) + geom_density()
  
  # Conditional faceting
  if(!is.null(facet_var)) p <- p + facet_wrap(vars(get(facet_var)))
  # plot
  p
}

univar_plot(mtcars, mpg, facet_var = "gear")


I'm not sure how to supply it as an unquoted variable - probably something with rlang or quote/substitute

Your code bombs on this line:
if(!is.null(facet_var)) 

The object gear is not found in the function environment. You need to tell R that it comes from your df. But you want the code to work if you pass nothing (NULL). One way to circumvent this problem is to add another argument, say "facet" which is FALSE by default.
univar_plot <- function(df, var, facet=FALSE, facet_var=NULL) {
  
  # create density plot
  p <- df |> ggplot(aes(x = {{var}})) + 
    geom_density()
  
  # Conditional faceting
  if(facet) {
    p <- p + facet_wrap(vars({{facet_var}}))
  }

  # plot
  p
}


univar_plot(mtcars, mpg) # still works
univar_plot(mtcars, mpg, facet=TRUE, facet_var=gear) # now works



Supplement @Dubukay's answer
If you want to use rlang, you can change your function to:
 if(!is.null(facet_var)) p <- p + ggplot2::facet_wrap(ggplot2::vars(!!sym(facet_var)))

univar_plot  <- function(df, var, facet_var = NULL){
  p <- df |> ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = {{var}})) + 
    ggplot2::geom_density()
  # if(!is.null(facet_var)) p <- p + ggplot2::facet_wrap(ggplot2::vars({{facet_var}}))
  if(!is.null(facet_var)) p <- p + ggplot2::facet_wrap(ggplot2::vars(!!sym(facet_var)))
  p
}
univar_plot (mtcars, mpg, facet_var = "gear")


